# The following matrix is invertible for all values of k except which one?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus

\begin{pmatrix}8&2\\ 5&k\end{pmatrix}

I know that to find the answer, I need to create the matrix above such that its determinant is 0. However, I am struggling on how I could do that.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The determinant is $8k -10$ and it is $0$ if and only if $k=10/8$.

Answer (score 0):

They got the above answer because the determinant of a $2 \times 2$ matrix is $ad - bc$. The they then set the determinant to zero and solved for $k$. To know which number corresponds to which letter: The top row of the matrix is $a,b$ and the bottom row is $c,d$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).